# how to stretch image vertically to 100% and crop horizontally

Tags: css

[Example page](http://test.doig.com.au/image-resize.html).

I would like to stretch the featured image `.entry-image-link img` vertically to 100% of the height of `div.entry-content`, and crop the extra width.

[image]

Can you help me do this please?

Comment: Have you tried putting the image inside a container of set width, hiding overflow, stretching the image inside the container, and zooming the image with the `zoom` property? I think that workflow or something along those lines would put you on the right track.

Comment: Add your codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Step1:

Make the parent-of-the parent's position relative.

#### Step2:

Make the parent's position absolute and height 100%;

#### Step3:

Make the image's position absolute and change its position and margin.

It's hard to move your whole section here, so I wrote a jQuery script to handle the style. You can just run the script on your site since you have jQuery on it. For others visitors, you can ignore the specific selectors.

```
var $=jQuery;
var $parentOfParent=$(".entry-content");
var $parent=$(".entry-image-link");
var $image=$(".entry-image-link img");

$parentOfParent.css("position","relative");
$parent.css({
    position: "absolute",
    height: "100%",
});
$image.css({
    height: "100%",
    'max-width': 'none',
    width: 'auto',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '-1000px',
    right: '-1000px',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    margin: 'auto',
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, although until the image loaded, things look warped...

Comment: Hi. Would you be able to help with the images in the sidebar beneath"Other Programs" [here](http://test.doig.com.au/vm-home.html) ? When the viewport is narrowed, the images do not reach full height of `.program`.

Comment: The problem there is similar with this one. You'd better understand the snippet above and solve that problem yourself. @Steve

Comment: Yes, I tried that first, replacing `var $parentOfParent=$(".entry-content");
var $parent=$(".entry-image-link"); var $image=$(".entry-image-link img");` with appropriate entries, but I see [this](http://imgur.com/fsHV1Yn).

Comment: No you can't just use the same code there. You should **understand** the code and port it to your new page. Try to modify some styles of the snippet and see what would happen, to understand why the code should be like that.

Answer (score 0):

If your .entry-content height is fixed then you can just hard code the height of your .entry-image-link

for an instance, if .entry-content height is 400px

then

```
.entry-image-link {
   height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: but that will warp the image's width, I need the photo's aspect ratio to remain the same, but have extra width cropped